# Efficient mapping of alike elements in different namespaces (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to translate XML->XML for several input documents that have "embedded" documents with different namespaces. These embedded documents have elements of the same type (i.e. based on same xsd) that i'd like to map in a generic way / template into the output document - regardless of the namespace.

Simple example Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message xmnls="mymessage">
    <Header>...</Header>
    <Body xmlns="type1">
        <DocumentType1>
            <Creditor>
                <Name>Mr Creditor</Name>
                <Address>Muddy Creek 42</Address>
            </Creditor>
            <CreditorAccount>
                <Id>794115296</Id>
            </CreditorAccount>
        </DocumentType1>
    </Body>
</Message>
```

Example Input XML 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message xmnls="mymessage">
    <Header>...</Header>
    <Body xmlns="type2"><!-- different namespace -->
        <DocumentType2>
            <Creditor><!-- same element -->
                <Name>Mr Creditor</Name> 
                <Address>Muddy Creek 42</Address>
            </Creditor>
            <CreditorAccount>
                <Id>794115296</Id>
            </CreditorAccount>
        </DocumentType2>
    </Body>
</Message>
```

For both examples, i'd like to extract the "Creditor" information which is structured the same way.
But as you see, Body-namespace ("type1", "type2"...) and child-Element name ("DocumentType1",...) varies, i.e. the whole name, not only the number at the end.

Output in both cases should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Request>
    <Creditor>
        <Name>Mr Creditor</Name>
        <Address>Muddy Creek 42</Address>
        <Account>794115296</Account>
    </Creditor>
</Request>
```

How can i map the Creditor information for both Messages-Examples in the Output format the best way with XSLT 1.0 / libxml+exslt? Regrettably I'm bound to 1.0.

I can use "wildcards" for sure, but i fear that might decrease performance. There will be a lot of mappings like this in the XSLT and more input data than the examples. Do you have expierences with that regarding performance?

Otherwise i would need a template for each different namespace, right? As I understood, there is no way to dynamically set an alias for a namespace in XSLT.

Here is an example XSLT using 'wildcards':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:mymessage="urn:mymessage"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl mymessage" 
                version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="//mymessage:Message">
    <Request>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Request>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="mymessage:Header"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Body']">
        <Creditor>
            <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="*/*[local-name()='Creditor']/*[local-name()='Name']"/>
            </Name>
            <Address>
                <xsl:value-of select="*/*[local-name()='Creditor']/*[local-name()='Address']"/>
            </Address>
            <Account>
                <xsl:value-of select="*/*[local-name()='CreditorAccount']/*[local-name()='Id']"/>
            </Account>
        </Creditor>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Do you have a list of all possible namespaces that `Body` and its descendants can be in?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: namespaces are in fact ISO20022 Message Types like "pacs.008.001.08", "pacs.004.001.09", "camt.053.001.08" and stuff like this. I will start with a set of let's say 5 Message Types but it might increase later. So yes, i have a full list but it's not exhaustive in terms of future adaptions.

Comment: @BusyBeaver Someone made a really bad design decision there. I'm sure they thought it was smart, but they had clearly never done any serious XML programming.

Comment: @MichaelKay i agree... imo this 'standard' is broken into pieces by each group using it's own set of messages with its own version (the version is part of the namespace, as in *.08, *.09 ...) and introducing subtle changes to suit their requirements. The intentions are good to structure financial information but in the end it is hidden in a bunch of 'dialects' leading to a lingual mess. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment on libxslt performance - but have you tried it? Write your code to be readable and maintainable, and only change it if that gives you a measurable performance problem.

An alternative approach when you want to handle input in multiple namespaces is to do two passes: the first pass strips out (or normalizes) the namespaces, the second pass then handles elements in a uniform namespace. For the first pass, just use `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">`

Obviously XSLT 2.0+ gives you the partial wildcard syntax `*:local` which makes this kind of code much more readable.

Comment: I did not run a deep test about performance. Thing is, i just used XSLT 2.0 first using the partial wildcard syntax you mentioned and it worked fine. Then I had to recode it to be compatible to XSLT 1.0 and my 'IDE' Altova XML Spy just hang and needed 10th the time. But i find your answer about the two runs quite helpful, i guess i can do this if the performance will be really this bad.  Thanks!

Comment: just for clarification - i used Altova XML Spy for the first implementation with XSLT 2.0, but then requirements have changed so it has to run on an libxml instance with XSLT 1.0 in the end...